# Are different meanings of quam and -quam related?

Tags: etymology, meaning

In Keller's Learn to Read Latin, I found that quam has several meanings:

> quam is the singular feminine accusative form of qui (interrogative or relative adj, what, which)

> quam (interrogative or relative adv.) how

> quam (conj.) than

Are those meaings of quam related to or originated from each other?

-quam is also used in forming other words:

> quisquam, quicquam (indef. pron.) someone, something; anyone, anything

> quisquam, quicquam is an indefinite pronoun formed by the addition of the indefinite suffix -quam to quis, quid.

> antequam or priusquam (conj.): before

> quamquam (conj.) although

> quam primum, as soon as possible

> umquam (adv.) ever

What does -quam mean in those compound words?

Are the meanings of -quam related to the meanings of quam?

Thanks.